# Michelson pairs not comparable

Tags: michelson

When I try to type the following Michelson script, I get a type error.

```
parameter unit;
storage (big_map (pair string address) (list timestamp));
code {CDR; NIL operation; PAIR};
```

```
Ill formed type.
At line 2 characters 17 to 37,
comparable type expected.Type pair string address is not comparable.
```

According to the [Michelson reference](https://michelson.nomadic-labs.com), types `pair ty1 ty2`, `address`, and `string` are comparable. Am I missing something? Is there are way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This feature is not totally implemented in Babylon (http://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/006_carthage.html#comparable-pairs-in-sets-and-maps), but it will arrive with Cartage in a few days if the vote is stakeholders vote for it. You can follow the election of Carthage at this address : https://tzstats.com/election/16

Comment: Tezos Agora is another good place to follow Tezos on-chain votes for new protocols https://www.tezosagora.org/